# How to read PKCS8 file with empty password using BouncyCastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#8

I can generate a PKCS#8 encrypted file with empty password using OpenSSL:

```
~ $ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in ca_private.pem 
Enter pass phrase for ca_private.pem:
Enter Encryption Password: <ENTER>
Verifying - Enter Encryption Password: <ENTER>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When reading this with a `PEMParser`, it returns an instance of `PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` (as expected).

Trying to decrypt that with `JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder`, however, fails with

> org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: password empty

There is a hard coded check for empty password when creating the decryption key. Is there a way around this? OpenSSL surely deals just fine reading the PKCS#8 back...

Sample code:

```java
import com.excelfore.api.lib.util.ApiCrypto;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.InputDecryptorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;

import java.io.FileReader;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(args[0])) {

            Object whatIsIt = new PEMParser(fr).readObject();
            if (whatIsIt instanceof PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) {
                PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) whatIsIt;
                InputDecryptorProvider provider =
                        new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().setProvider(ApiCrypto.bouncyCastleProvider).build(args[1].toCharArray());
                pInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(provider);
                System.out.println("ok");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I don't want "+whatIsIt.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to handle this?

Comment: @JúlioFalbo Dave Thompson's answer works, but it relies on precise order of loaded providers, which I found not feasible (I don't want bouncy provider to be registered at all, it messes up larger frameworks), so I just require that PKCS#8 keys have a password, otherwise PKCS#1 keys are to be used.

Comment: Strange, because it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is what you expect or not (do not test yet with empty passphrase)

```
    public static KeyPair parseKeyPair(Path pemFile, String passPhrase) {
        try(PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(Files.newBufferedReader(pemFile))) {
            Object object = pemParser.readObject();
            JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProviderHolder.BC_PROVIDER);
            if(object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
                if(passPhrase == null)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pass phrase required for parsing RSA private key");

                PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build(passPhrase.toCharArray());
                return converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object).decryptKeyPair(decProv));
            }
            if(object instanceof PEMKeyPair) {
                return converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new PicApplicationException("Couldn't parse pem to keypair", e);
        }

        throw new PicApplicationException("Couldn't parse pem to keypair");
    }
```

You may pass empty passphrase to this line:

```
PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build("".toCharArray());
```

Comment: That code is for OpenSSL _traditional_ aka _legacy_ PEM files, not PKCS8 as specified for this Q. Plus even for trad it doesn't work for empty passphrase: you can _build_ the DecryptorProvider but _using_ it for decrypt fails. Although this is somewhat offset by the fact OpenSSL commandline won't write a trad file using an empty passphrase, like it will for pkcs8; you have to write a program to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The *BouncyCastle* provider will not use an empty passphrase for PKCS8 decryption (actually any PBE). The SunJCE provider will, BUT you cannot specify it explicitly as the provider to use, because it *doesn't* handle AlgorithmParameters for the cipher by OID for PBES2; instead you must let the DecryptorProvider use the default JCA search and have Bouncy provider in that search *after* SunJCE; the simplest way is to put it at the end with `Security.addProvider`:

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    try( Reader r = new FileReader(args[0]); PEMParser p = new PEMParser(r) ) {
        JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder b = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder();
        //DON'T:if( args.length>1 ) b.setProvider(args[1]);
        InputDecryptorProvider d = b.build(new char[0]);
        PrivateKeyInfo k0 = ((PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo)p.readObject()).decryptPrivateKeyInfo(d);
        PrivateKey k1 = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPrivateKey(k0);
        System.out.println (k1.getAlgorithm());
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the order of the providers matter. To convert the passphrase into the key, `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory` is used, which iterates over all registered providers until it finds one that returns the key successfully. Though conditions probably apply, and it's JDK implementation dependent.

Comment: Did not work for me